# Java generics vs C# where keyword

Tags: c#, java, generics, where-clause

I have a method in a C# project that looks like this

```
public T AddEC<T>() where T : EntityComponent, new() {
    if (!HasEC<T>())
    {
      T nComponent = new T();
    }
}
```

Now I have only recently started properly working with Java Generics, but I have no idea how i'd port a method like this, or if its even possible due to the language constraints, can anyone help?

Comment: I made a post about this http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/c-said-java-said-oop-for-generics.html

Comment: It's not only about erasure, Java probably wouldn't support structural typing like this even if it had reified generics.

Comment: You're a god sent Michael Buen. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, I strongly disagree about this being "too localized". I doubt the OP is the only C# developer who wonders about Java generics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good article.

http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/2007/Aug-31.html

From that source

> Java type and method constraints are specified using a "mini
>   expression language" within the '<' and '>' declaring the generic type
>   parameters. For each type parameter that has constraints, the syntax
>   is:
>
> ```
> TypeParameter ListOfConstraints
> ```
>
> Where `ListOfConstraints` is a '&'-separated list of one of the
>   following constraints:
>
> - Specifying a base class or implemented interface on the Generic
>     Type Argument by using: extends BaseOrInterfaceType
>
> ('&' must be used instead of ',' because ',' separates each generic
>   type parameter.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
class GenericClass<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
    void print (T t) {
        System.out.println (t.intValue ()); // OK
    }
}
```

In this example Number and Comparable are the constraints as they would appear in the where clause of a C# class declaration.

Comment: In my example i'm not using where in the definition of a C# class though, its there as an example of a method within a class. I've got a basic understanding of how to confine constraints, especially in classes. I tried creating a method defined as the following (in Java)

`public <T extends EntityComponent> T addEC(Class<T> entity) {`

but that doesn't do what I want it to do really. I need it to work as my C# example. :(